# A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1]

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON file and i am trying to deal with but the following error is appears:

> Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
>       at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:433)
>       at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:195)
>       at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:319)
>       at amazondataset.AmazonDataset.main(AmazonDataset.java:11)
>   Java Result: 1

This is a sample of the file:

```
{ "reviewerID": "A2SUAM1J3GNN3B", 
  "asin": "0000013714", 
  "reviewerName": "J. McDonald", 
  "helpful": [2, 3], 
  "reviewText": "I bought this for my husband who plays the piano. He is having a wonderful time playing these old hymns. The music is at times hard to read because we think the book was published for singing from more than playing from. Great purchase though!", 
  "overall": 5.0, 
  "summary": "Heavenly Highway Hymns", 
  "unixReviewTime": 1252800000, 
  "reviewTime": "09 13, 2009" 
}
```

and this is my code, simply:

```
JSONObject ar = new JSONObject("E:\\amazonDS.json");

    for (int i = 0; i < ar.length(); i++) {
       System.out.println( "Name: " + ar.getString("reviewerName").toString() );            
    }
```

Comment: You need a `JSONObject`, not a `JSONArray`.

Comment: because it's not array (as error states array must start with "["), its object

Comment: plus look for the `helpful`

Comment: same problem !! ||   JSONObject ar = new JSONObject("E:\\amazonDS.json");
        
        for (int i = 0; i < ar.length(); i++) {
           System.out.println( "Name: " + ar.getString("reviewerName").toString() );            
        }

Comment: @Belal Post your code and error message when you use `JSONObject jo = new JSONObject("E:\\amazonDS.json");`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to read the content of the file first, because the constructor of [JSONArray](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/blob/master/JSONArray.java) needs the file-content and not the file-path.

```
new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(new FileInputStream(new File("path"), "UTF-8")));

new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(new FileReader("path")));
```

*update*
You should use a filereader or specify the charset for the FileInputStream