# Reading in JSON files using Eclipse, do I need a library or not

Tags: java, json

I need to read a JSON file input from a file into my Java program. 
I found some code that is reasonable to use which I have an example below. 
But I am using Eclipse and I getting errors trying to reference JSONObject.
So apparently I do not have a library intalled in eclipse. So I was wondering what is the easiest way to get this to work. Do I need whole big library installed or  is there another way without. If I do need to install a library which is the best/easiest and could you point to a link for download.

Thanks!!

```
        String jsonData = "";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        String line;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathname));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            jsonData += line + "\n";
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)
                br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    // System.out.println("File Content: \n" + jsonData);
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonData);
```

Comment: You will need a library. I assume youre are trying to use jsson.org Java:

https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java

Comment: `JSONObject` is not part of the standard Java libraries, so, yes, you need a separate library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `JSONObject` is not part of the JDK so indeed you need to import a library to your project to be able to execute your code.

You can get it from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20160810) of if you use maven simply add the next dependency to the pom file of your project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20160810</version>
</dependency>
```

Finally please note that your code can be simplified by using a `JSONTokener` to be able parse a `JSON` content from an `InputStream` or a `Reader` which seems to be much more appropriate in your case, so your code should be:

```
JSONObject obj;
try (InputStream input = new FileInputStream(pathname)) {
    obj = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(input));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference a json library. Following is really lightweight: https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java

An example for reading JSON can be found in following Question:

[A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39979590/a-jsonarray-text-must-start-with-at-1-character-2-line-1/39979739#39979742)

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend this one:
JSON simple

https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/

If all you want is to do is read and write, this is the lightest version, I think.

Answer (score -1):

after get string your jsondata, you have to parse it. there is a example

```
 public static List<String> GetCodes(String json)
        {
            try {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
                for(int i = 0, limit = jsonArray.length(); i < limit; i++)
                {
                    JSONObject j = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    list.add(j.getString("Code"));
                }
                return list;
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: OP is asking which library he has to import. The parsing code is already present in his question.

Comment: He can use JSONObject, so he can use this code without library for json.