# How to solve "A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1] in java

Tags: java, json

I am trying convert a string into a jsonArray and then check a value in that if that is null or not. I have converted the string into jsonArray and using the logic to check the null value but sometimes i am getting the exception

```
A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
```

I am posting the code here what i have used

```
public static boolean validateRecods(String itemRequest){
 boolean isPrice  =  false;
 if(!itemRequest.equals("")){
   JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(itemRequest); //here i am converting it to jsonArray
   for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
     JSONObject exprObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
     if(!(exprObject.opString("newP").isEmpty() || exprObject.opsString("newP").equals(""){
      isPrice = true;
    }
  }
 return isPrice;
}
```

And below is the jsonArray string what i am getting

```
"[{"key":"234","Item_no":"1223","newP":"","date":"2021-0916"}]"
```

And below is the jsonObject which is forming

```
 "{"key":"234","Item_no":"1223","newP":"","date":"2021-0916"}"
```

I can see the JSONArray forming with '[' bracket , but sometimes the exception is occured . I am not sure about the reason why it is causing.

Comment: Does using `JSONObject` insted helps ? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39979590/a-jsonarray-text-must-start-with-at-1-character-2-line-1

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez already used see my code  JSONObject exprObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

Comment: use it instead of `new JSONArray` and also try it removing the square brackets

Comment: Your date string looks strange: `2021-0916` Shouldn't that be `2021-09-16` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A JSONArray text must start with '\[' at 1 \[character 2 line 1\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39979590/a-jsonarray-text-must-start-with-at-1-character-2-line-1)